# I changed Visual Studio Code scale setting, now can't change it back

Tags: visual-studio-code

I increased the window scale size (exactly don't know the name).
Its default is 0 or 1, i increased it to 100.
Now I can't change because the interface is increased full.
Now scrolling is not working to reach down and also array buttons too

Ctr +, and ctr - minus are also not working.
I think I only have the option to reset all my Visual studios with some keyboard shortcuts

[image: Visual studio Code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try looking into the settings file and check if there is a setting for zoom or scale or something like that.

The settings file is usually located in one of these locations:

> Depending on your platform, the user settings file is located here:
>
> - Windows `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`
> - macOS `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`
> - Linux `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`
>
> The workspace settings file is located under the `.vscode` folder in your root folder.

[More info on the official help site](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)